# Can't get form values from a submitted form within a list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

in jQuery, I am dynamically creating list items and each contains a small form with hidden fields. The form IDs are created dynamically and it is written back to an ID. This all works fine. My problem is that when I hit the select button on one of the list items, I can't get the values of the inputs within the form. Ideas anyone?

```
    $(document).on('click', '.select-button', function(e) {
        var selectedFormID = $(this).parent().attr("id"); // gets the ID of the form selected
        document.getElementById(selectedFormID).submit(); // submits the correct <li><form> selected
            userzip = $("#userzip").val(); // can't get any of these values 
            services = $("#services").val();
    });
```

If I were to use:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form_someID', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            userzip = $("#userzip").val();
            services = $("#services").val();
            alert(services);
});
```

This works fine... but the ID is static which doesn't help.. I need to submit *ONLY* the form of the selected list item.

Any input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: where is the HTML code ?

Comment: Sorry.. I created a pen that illustrates the issue.. no matter which one is clicked, they both return the values from the first list item:
https://codepen.io/SimplyMarkB/pen/abOwGQg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` must be unique per document, you can use `name` per form

```js
$(document).on('click', '.ss-select-location', function(e) {
  var $form = $(this).closest('form');
  var userzip = $form.find('[name=userzip]').val();
  var services = $form.find('[name=services]').val();

  alert(services);

  $form.submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="locations-list" class="accordion">
  <li class="accordion-item">
    <h3 class="accordion-thumb">
      Lower Manahattan
      <span class="ss-distance">
                (0 mi away)
            </span>
    </h3>
    <div id="location_NYC01" class="accordion-panel step-two">
      <form id="locationForm_NYC01" class="locationForm" method="post">
        <div class="row ss-address">
          <div class="col-6">
            1313 mockingbird lane
            <br> Suite 500
            <br> New York, NY 10018
            <br> (212) 555-1212
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 ss-hours">
            Sun
            <span class="ss-time">
                            closed
                        </span>
            <br> Mon
            <span class="ss-time">
                            9:00am - 6:00pm
                        </span>
            <br> Tue
            <span class="ss-time">
                            9:00am - 8:00pm
                        </span>
            <br> Wed
            <span class="ss-time">
                            9:00am - 8:00pm
                        </span>
            <br> Thur
            <span class="ss-time">
                            9:00am - 8:00pm
                        </span>
            <br> Fri
            <span class="ss-time">
                            9:00am - 6:00pm
                        </span>
            <br> Sat
            <span class="ss-time">
                            8:00am - 5:00pm
                        </span>
          </div>
          <input name="userzip" type="hidden" value="10018">
          <input name="shortcode" type="hidden" value="NYC01">
          <input name="services" type="hidden" value="NYC01 values">
          <input name="sources" type="hidden" value="NYC01 values">
          <input name="corporate" type="hidden" value="1">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="ss-select-location">
                                        Select This Location
                                    </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="accordion-item">
    <h3 class="accordion-thumb">
      Queens
      <span class="ss-distance">
                (20 mi away)
            </span>
    </h3>
    <div id="location_NYC04" class="accordion-panel step-two">
      <form id="locationForm_NYC04" class="locationForm" method="post">
        <div class="row ss-address">
          <div class="col-6">
            3100 elfenview lane
            <br> Suite 100
            <br> Rosedale, NY 10020
            <br> (212) 555-1214
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 ss-hours">
            Sun
            <span class="ss-time">
                            closed
                        </span>
            <br> Mon
            <span class="ss-time">
                            9:00am - 6:00pm
                        </span>
            <br> Tue
            <span class="ss-time">
                            9:00am - 8:00pm
                        </span>
            <br> Wed
            <span class="ss-time">
                            9:00am - 8:00pm
                        </span>
            <br> Thur
            <span class="ss-time">
                            9:00am - 8:00pm
                        </span>
            <br> Fri
            <span class="ss-time">
                            9:00am - 6:00pm
                        </span>
            <br> Sat
            <span class="ss-time">
                            8:00am - 5:00pm
                        </span>
          </div>
          <input name="userzip" type="hidden" value="10020">
          <input name="shortcode" type="hidden" value="NYC04">
          <input name="services" type="hidden" value="NYC04 values">
          <input name="sources" type="hidden" value="NYC04 values">
          <input name="corporate" type="hidden" value="1">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="ss-select-location">
                                        Select This Location
                                    </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Abdelrahman - I just tested in my environment and it works great! Thank you!